# Meteor: Can filter a collection by _id but I can't filter a collection using other fields

Tags: meteor

I'm fairly new to meteor and I'm still trying to find my way around with filtering collections. Here is my problem, I have a collection defined as follows;

```
parent_id: {
    label: 'Parent ID',
    type: String,
  },
ar_session_id: {
    label: 'Session ID',
    type: String,
  },
```

I have inserted some documents and here is one;

```
{
  "_id" : "oQdtbBtKXHzdxWvzn",
  "parent_id" : "dJkbDBXut5WzwkaFN",
  "ar_session_id" : "dJkbDBXut5WzwkaFNuz77MFgcuGyvgokip",
  "question" : "Do you have blah blah...?",
  "answer" : "no",
  "createdAt" : 1564563509127
}
```

I am able to filter using `parent_id` but I can't filter using `ar_session_id`

```
var parent_id = "dJkbDBXut5WzwkaFN";
var ar_session_id = "dJkbDBXut5WzwkaFNuz77MFgcuGyvgokip";

qry1 = AssessmentResponse.find({parent_id: parent_id}).fetch();
qry2 = AssessmentResponse.find({ar_session_id: ar_session_id}).fetch();
```

`qry2` returns an empty set. What is it that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I could think of would be if you are not publishing `ar_session_id` in the client.

For instance if you had something like this:

```js
Meteor.publish("AssessmentResponse", function () {
  return AssessmentResponse.find({}, { fields: { ar_session_id: 0 } });
});
```

Otherwise there is no reason the filtering would be empty, assuming you don't have any typo.